# Parsing T-SQL statements to tokens

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, parsing

You can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164730.aspx) how nicely `C#`code statement is parse to tokens. For example, the following code:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        public void MyFunction(int arg1)
        {
            int var1 = arg1;
        }
    }
}
```

is parsed to this:

[image]

I want to do something like this but with `T-SQL` statement instead. For example, if I have the following `T-SQL` statement:

```
IIF(COALESCE([Col001], [Col002], [Col003]) > [Col004], [Col005] * [Col006] + ISNULL([Col007], [Col008]), CONCAT(SUBSTRING([Col009], 0, 3), 'sample text', [Col010]))
```

will give me something like this:

```
IIF, COALESCE, ISNULL, CONCAT, SUBSTRING    - functions 
[Col001], [Col002], ... , [Col010]          - columns 
0, 3, 'sample text'                         - variables
```

or in case I have:

```
ISNULL([Col001], [Col002], [Col003])
```

structure with errors:

```
[The isnull function requires 2 argument(s).] - error
```

There are not any free or paid up-to-date solutions and it seems to use the Microsoft parser is the best solution here. As I have read I need to use the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.Parser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx) namespace, but there are not any examples and I was not able to split the `T-SQL` statement the way I like. Also, it seems to work only with complete statements (you need `SELECT` clause for example, and I need to use it for code fragments only).

Can I do this using this namespace or it's better to start writing `C#` class for my needs instead?

Comment: Even if you were able to use it, you thought about the fact that you can't probably "package" it together with your app, because it isn't licensed for this?

Comment: @xanatos I am not sure I have understand you. I guess I am able to use this namespace if it is possible. While I was searching I have found some paid solutions for `T-SQL` parsers but they are not up-to-date (working with SQL Server 2008, and I am usingt SQL Server 2012/2014)

Comment: I think xanatos makes a valid point here. I would use [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) anyway, or [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/).

Comment: There is at least another "microsoft" class for parsing TSQL: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.transactsql.scriptdom.aspx Someone here http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/sqlandthelike/archive/2012/08/29/reporting-on-common-code-smells-a-poc.aspx wrote even a library using it

Comment: ANTLR is used by ASP.NET MVC and a *lot* of other projects. Several SQL dialects are already available

Comment: This is not valid SQL -- you are showing Access SQL here.

Comment: @Hogan It is 100% valid `T_SQL` statement executed in `SQL Server 2012`. Don't be mislead by the `IIF` and `COALESCE` function :-)

Comment: COALESCE is a standard SQL function -- IIF is not.

Comment: @Hogan [IIF is standard T-SQL function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had to add the reference manually in the csproj

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91

Like

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
```

A simple example:

```
string sql = "IIF(COALESCE([Col001], [Col002], [Col003]) > [Col004], [Col005] * [Col006] + ISNULL([Col007], [Col008]), CONCAT(SUBSTRING([Col009], 0, 3), 'sample text', [Col010]))";

var po = new ParseOptions { };
var scanner = new Scanner(po);
scanner.SetSource(sql, 0);

Tokens token;
int state = 0;
int start;
int end;
bool isPairMatch;
bool isExecAutoParamHelp;

while ((token = (Tokens)scanner.GetNext(ref state, out start, out end, out isPairMatch, out isExecAutoParamHelp)) != Tokens.EOF)
{
    string str = sql.Substring(start, end - start + 1);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", token, str);
}
```

<s>Taken from http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/dave_ballantynes_blog/2012/03/13/parsing-t-sql-the-easy-way/</s>

Taken from [Parsing T-SQL – The easy way](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/parsing-t-sql-%E2%80%93-the-easy-way)

Note that this parser recognizes a certain number of functions (like `IIF`, `COALESCE`, ...). Unrecognized functions are simply marked as `TOKEN_ID`, like column names.

Comment: I have to admit this is a working example even thought it's not what I am looking for. I am going to try to write mine parser as the other parsers offered are too complex for my needs and the solution with the namespace above doesn't meet them too.

Comment: @gotqn You have to remember that the parser you suggested isn't a parser used by the compiler, it is a parser used by the syntax highlighter...