# Regex parse sql string

Tags: c#, sql, regex, parsing

I have sql string like

```
select * from dbo.Person where Person  = ? AND Name = ? OR (Country = ? OR City = 1)
```

If it's possible to get string array like below with Regex in C#

```
result[0] = Person = ?
result[1] = Name = ?
result[2] = (Country = ? OR City = 1)
```

thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to parse sql yourself? If so, why?

Comment: what you mean by `from dbo.Person where Person` is person is table name as well as column name?

Comment: Is this necessary for a real world application? If so, in my humble opinion, it shouldn't..

Comment: Yes It is Possible so for you make the regex  and for that you use Regex.Matches(string, regex) .

Comment: .NET has this functionality built in. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.parser.aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452864/parsing-t-sql-statements-to-tokens)

Answer (score 1):

First try looks like this

```
var s = @"select* from dbo.Person where Person = ? AND Name = ? OR (Country = ? OR City = 1)";

 var reg = new Regex("[A-Za-z]+ = [A-Za-z0-9?]+");

var result =  reg.Matches(s);
```

Something like that but is no Regex

```
  var s = @"select* from dbo.Person where Person = ? AND Name = ? OR(Country = ? OR City = 1)";

  var s1 = s.Split(new[] { "where" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

  var s2 = s1.Split(new[] { "OR", "AND" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: You regex doesn't match `result[2] = (Country = ? OR City = 1)` as one match. [It](https://regex101.com/r/bB0sK0/1) matches `Country = ?` and `City = 1` as two different matches.

Answer (score 1):

If you need anything more complicated than this, it's going to quickly go beyond what you can easily solve with regex. I have released a free parser on GitHub that will parse out TSQL in a stable way into the pieces, [TSQL Parser](https://github.com/bruce-dunwiddie/tsql-parser) . You can also use the Microsoft TSQL parser, [using the TSqlParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1779737/using-the-tsqlparser) . With either of these, they will break it out a little more granular than you're requesting, which you will then have to piece back together based on parenthesis for example.